# Why am I keep getting a UnicodeDecodeError in pandas read_csv() function even though I specified the correct encoding parameter?

Tags: python, pandas, utf-8, character-encoding

I downloaded the [sentiment140](http://help.sentiment140.com/for-students) dataset and tried opening it using `pd.read_csv()` and I got the `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 232719-232720: invalid continuation byte`

Then, I specified the 'utf-8' encoding parameter in the `read_csv()` function after getting the file encoding info using the unix file command but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: `utf-8` was the default, so don't expect specifying `utf-8` to fix it.  It's not `utf-8`.  Figure out what the real encoding is and specify that.

Comment: @MarkTolonen thanks man, it seems that the actual encoding was **latin1**

Comment: Maybe, `latin1` can decode anything without error, but it isn't necessarily correct.  If the CSV was created on Windows, it is more likely `cp1252`, which has some extra code points like the euro sign and smart quotes that would be mis-decoded with `latin1`.